# Write a function to copy 0-15 bits into 16-31

Tags: c++

How to write a function to copy 0-15 bits into 16-31?

```
unsigned int n = 10; // 1010

copyFromTo(n);
assert(n == 655370);

n = 5;
copyFromTo(n);
assert(n == 327685);

n = 134;
copyFromTo(n);
assert(n == 8781958);
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? How did, or didn't, it work? What are the actual results?

Comment: @MatthewMoss: Why 65537. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, should multiplying by 65536 correspond to a 16 bit left shift?

Comment: @therainmaker: Add one to preserve the value in the lower 16 bits, as well as copying it to the upper 16. Assuming the input value fits into those bits.

Comment: @therainmaker But he's asking for *copy*, not *move*.  On the other hand, while my comment answer works for some inputs, it's a joke answer. And the problem is underspecified. And wait 'til the teacher tests with an input like 1234567. 'Cause, internet!

Answer (score 2):

You want to copy the bits in 0-15 to 16-31. You should understand that multiplying by 2 is equivalent to shifting the bits of the number once to the left (moving to higher bits).

If your number is `n`, `n << 16` would be shifting your number 16 bits to the left. This is equivalent to multiplying n with the 16th power of 2, which happens to be 65536.

To copy the bits, and keep the original bits in 0-15, the command `n = n + (n << 16);` should work. However, the issue with this is (as pointed out in the comments), that the upper 16-31 bits are still set in `n +` term. We also need to clear these bits. Note that 65535 corresponds to 2^16 - 1, and would have the first 0-15 bits as 1, and others as 0. So the correct command would be `n = (n && 65535) + (n << 16);`

Comment: I suppose for this assignment, `n` is going to be less than 65536 to begin with. Otherwise, you might want to mask off the upper 16 bits of `n` when you add it to `n << 16`...  and use bitwise-or rather than addition.

Comment: Even if the number is bigger than 65536, shifting it would automatically remove the upper bits as they would overflow. So, I don't think there is a need to mask the upper 16 bits, (unless you mean something else by masking). I think bitwise OR will give issues if the number is bigger than 65536.

Comment: Those upper bits remain in the `n +` portion.

Comment: @therainmaker: If the number is bigger than 65536, then there are already some bits set in the upper 16. You'd need to clear them before copying the lower 16.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
void copyFromTo(unsigned int& n)
{
    n = (n & 0xffff) * 0x00010001;
}
```

Comment: That looks familiar...  ;)

Comment: @MatthewMoss And less cryptic ;)

Comment: And no more correct, if the input is too large.

Answer (score 0):

n << 16 to shift bits would do it, to move lower bits to upper? (edited) And after that, copying just the lower 16 bits into it

Comment: He wants the bits copied, not moved.